# How to run this Python program

Tags: python

I know exactly 0 things about coding (unless HTML is coding?) and joined the site specifically for this question.

I found this code on Reddit and I'd really like to use the program, but I have zero knowledge of how to do that. I installed Python and have no idea how it works. I just need the very basic, click-this-button, type-this-here step-by-step of how to get an output and edit the variables.

The explanation of the program: https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/1tpj38/random_royal_family_tree_generation/

The code is linked in the post but here it is again just in case: http://pastebin.com/uk9xG4XQ

I'm running Windows 10 and Python 3.5

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to learn a bit about programming Python. That's some work but we can't do it for you. Please also see [what questions to ask on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: So you're going to run some random code downloaded online without having any idea whatsoever what it does? Good luck with that.

Comment: I understand what it does obviously, that's why I want to run it. I just can't figure out how because I'm not familiar with Python.

Is it really that complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really eager to run the program without learning Python then do the following:

1. Download the file and save it as `Dy27u.py`
2. Open the file in notepad, find the line that says `folder = '' #'/media/ToshikHD/Dropbox/Programming/Python/Dy/'` and change the path to point to wherever you saved the file. Save the file, making sure you retain the .py extension
3. Open command prompt or powershell in Windows
4. Use `cd` to navigate to the folder where the file is stored. You make have to google this step to learn how to navigate around your file system if you don't already know hot do
5. Once you're in the correct directory, type `python Dy27u.py`

Taking a closer look at the code, you also need some extra text files called `FemaleNames.txt`, `MaleNames.txt`, and `LastNames.txt`. Read the comments in the .py file your downloaded so you know how to format those files

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out I had a problem with locating where I installed Python, but I got the program running thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Download the code in the python format (.py), open up PowerShell (comes with Windows 10), find your way to the directory you downloaded the .py format code to using the `cd [X]` command (where X is the directory), then type `python3 X` with X being whatever you saved the .py as.